# Jquery animate

Tags: jquery, animate

Есть код

```
$("#mobile").mouseenter(function() {        
   $(this).animate({backgroundColor: 'rgba(205,205,255,0.1)'}, 160);
}).mouseleave(function() {
   $(this).animate({backgroundColor: 'rgba(205,205,255,0.02)'}, 350);
});
```

Рабочий, но если много раз быстро наводишь мышкой на блок получается светофор. Как устранить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[документация найдёт ответ](http://api.jquery.com/stop/)

Comment: Т.е. вам, @timmi, нужно перед следующей анимацией остановить предыдущую. Ваш К.О. :)

Comment: Останавливать надо анимацию и запускать, как то на ExtJS попадал с таким трюком но че -то сам сообразил (: